# Pull Huge Docker Image

Tags: docker, hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop sandbox image following the link
https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/sandbox-deployment-and-install-guide/section/3/#deploy-hdp-sandbox

docker image size is approximately 11GB,

At the end of the pull process, I get following error and process is interrupted.

It might be a max size limit to pull it down? Do you know what the problem is?

```
mypc:HDP_3.0.1_docker-deploy-scripts_18120587fc7fb mypc$ sh docker-deploy-hdp30.sh 
+ registry=hortonworks
+ name=sandbox-hdp
+ version=3.0.1
+ proxyName=sandbox-proxy
+ proxyVersion=1.0
+ flavor=hdp
+ echo hdp
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.d
+ mkdir -p sandbox/proxy/conf.stream.d
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1
3.0.1: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
70799bbf2226: Pulling fs layer 
40963917cdad: Pulling fs layer 
3fe9adbb8d7e: Pulling fs layer 
ee3ec4e8cb3d: Pulling fs layer 
7ea5917732c0: Pulling fs layer 
2d951411620c: Pulling fs layer 
f4c5e354e7fd: Pulling fs layer 
22ffa6ef360f: Pulling fs layer 
2060aa0f3751: Pull complete 
ca01ba34744d: Pull complete 
83326dded077: Pull complete 
eb3d71b90b73: Pull complete 
bdd1cab41c81: Pull complete 
500cc770c4bd: Pull complete 
0cb1decd5474: Pull complete 
b9591f4b6855: Pull complete 
f28e56086127: Pull complete 
e7de4e7d0bca: Pull complete 
ec77967d2166: Pull complete 
4fdcae170114: Pull complete 
6347f5df8ffc: Pull complete 
6a6ecc232709: Pull complete 
ea845898ff50: Pull complete 
02135573b1bf: Pull complete 
cb0176867cd8: Pull complete 
3c08321268fd: Pull complete 
82e82a97c465: Pull complete 
8aaaa48ed101: Pull complete 
74b321ac2ac5: Pull complete 
569da02c0a66: Pull complete 
af40820407ef: Downloading [==============>                                    ]  3.333GB/11.37GB
af40820407ef: Downloading [===================>                               ]  3.148GB/8.041GB
af40820407ef: Retrying in 1 second 




af40820407ef: Retrying in 1 second 
Get https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/af/af40820407ef8e6b1f249b672c108899306f03e466a39dc163386cb5b0e2713f/data?verify=1554111201-vOu%2FJPy3eH%2Fqp5XdIYIDr67Mtpc%3D: read tcp 192.168.65.3:37404->192.168.65.1:3129: read: connection reset by peer
+ docker pull hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
1.0: Pulling from hortonworks/sandbox-proxy
Digest: sha256:42e4cfbcbb76af07e5d8f47a183a0d4105e65a1e7ef39fe37ab746e8b2523e9e
Status: Image is up to date for hortonworks/sandbox-proxy:1.0
+ '[' hdp == hdf ']'
+ '[' hdp == hdp ']'
+ hostname=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com
++ docker images
++ grep hortonworks/sandbox-hdp
++ awk '{print $2}'
+ version=
+ docker network create cda
+ docker run --privileged --name sandbox-hdp -h sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com --network=cda --network-alias=sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com -d hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
+ echo ' Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait'
 Remove existing postgres run files. Please wait
+ sleep 2
+ docker exec -t sandbox-hdp sh -c 'rm -rf /var/run/postgresql/*; systemctl restart postgresql-9.6.service;'
Error: No such container: sandbox-hdp
+ sed s/sandbox-hdp-security/sandbox-hdp/g assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ mv -f assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh.new assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ chmod +x assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ assets/generate-proxy-deploy-script.sh
+ uname
+ grep MINGW
+ chmod +x sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
+ sandbox/proxy/proxy-deploy.sh
sandbox-proxy
30ee1449d9388665922a8e413a7fd9c56c40456cb9862e0507138daccbc0f16d
```

## Here is my docker disk allocation

```
$ docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              6                   6                   1.058GB             75.99MB (7%)
Containers          44                  0                   3.393MB             3.393MB (100%)
Local Volumes       70                  58                  1.169MB             10.27kB (0%)
Build Cache         0                   0                   0B                  0B
```

Comment: I'm not sure. but you could check Docker's configuration to make sure the hard disk allocation is big enough.

Answer (score 0):

Prune solves my problem.

```
>Docker image prune
>Docker container prune
```